# Resource about Supercontinuum Generation in Fibers

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, non-linear-optics, fiber-optics

I would like to consult a nice reference that explains the theoretical background of SC generation in optical fibers in detail but more or less self-contained. I would also like to have your opinions on nonlinear optic books that present material at introductory level.

Answer (score 0):

Ancient question, but here goes...

Supercontinuum generation is a very large field, so no one source will provide a complete explanation but here are a couple of pointers to start with.

There is a very good review of supercontinuum generation pumped in the anomalous dispersion regime [here](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.78.1135).

[Here's](https://www.osapublishing.org/josab/abstract.cfm?uri=josab-27-3-550) an article on SCG pumped in the normal dispersion regime which demonstrates optical wave breaking as a broadband source of coherent radiation.

You will find lots of excellent references both in the bibliographies of those two articles and by checking their citing articles, so I won't list any more here. Also, once you have found a few papers that you like, check their department or university library websites for theses written by the corresponding author, because these usually have a lot of good introductory material.

The standard text book for nonlinear fibre optics is by [Agrawal](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Nonlinear_Fiber_Optics.html?id=b5S0JqHMoxAC&redir_esc=y).

'Nonlinear Optics' by Robert Boyd and 'Quantum Nonlinear Optics' by Amnon Yariv are also excellent sources for general nonlinear optics info. If I remember rightly then neither address supercontinuum generation directly, but the highly relevant Kerr nonlinearity is detailed extensively in both.